# How should make this relationship and access data in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 4 tables:

**Table name: clients**

Fields: id, name, slug

**Table name: projects**

Fields: id, slug

**Table name: project_translation**

Fields: id, locale, project_id, title

**Table name: client_project**

Fields: id, client_id, project_id

**Relationships**

In the **Project model**

```
public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class,'client_project')->withTimestamps();
        //return $this->belongsToMany('Client')->withTimestamps()->orderBy('priority', 'desc');
    }
```

In the **Client model**

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class,'client_project')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function translate()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProjectTranslation::class,'project_translations')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In **Client_Project model**

```
public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client');
    }
```

In **ProjectTranslation model**

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Client');

    }
```

And I'm trying to **access data** in controller like this:

```
$client_project = Client::find($id)->translate;
        return $client_project;
```

This give me the next error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique 
table/alias: 'project_translations' (SQL: select 
`project_translations`.*, `project_translations`.`client_id` as 
`pivot_client_id`, `project_translations`.`project_translation_id` as 
`pivot_project_translation_id`, `project_translations`.`created_at` as 
`pivot_created_at`, `project_translations`.`updated_at` as 
`pivot_updated_at` from `project_translations` inner join 
`project_translations` on `project_translations`.`id` = 
`project_translations`.`project_translation_id` where `project_translations`.`client_id` = 22)
```

I'm not sure, but I think something is wrong with Relationships.

I'm in Client blade, and I want to show the projectstranslations of the projects of this client.

Comment: you should probably write how you created tables

Comment: You have two entries for ``project_translations`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`` I don't use eloquent or laravel so as to why, I don't know.  But that is the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here I formatted you query so it's readable, as I said in the comments I am not a laravel user.  But I know Sql

```
select 
    `project_translations`.*,
    `project_translations`.`client_id` as `pivot_client_id`,
    `project_translations`.`project_translation_id` as `pivot_project_translation_id`,
    `project_translations`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`,
    `project_translations`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`
from 
    `project_translations`  <-- Duplicate Table with no alias
inner join 
    `project_translations` on `project_translations`.`id` = `project_translations`.`project_translation_id`
where
    `project_translations`.`client_id` = 22
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `Client_Project` model.

In the **Project model**

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class,'client_project')->withTimestamps();
}

public function translates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectTranslation::class);
}
```

In the  **Client model** :

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class,'client_project')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In the **ProjectTranslation model** :

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project');
}
```

In the controller :

```
$client_projects = Client::find($id)->projects; //all client projects
return $client_projects;
```

In the view after geting this `$client_projects` and looping over it you can get the translations of a project by :

```
$client_project->translates  // for single projects you will get its translates :)
```

For Project you have [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with clients and it has [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) translates => in the documentation links there are many examples :)

Comment: In Blade I should make: `@foreach ($client_projects as $project) {{$project->translates}} @endforeach` But it's now working, how I should do it in blade? @Maraboc

Comment: Ok, with {{$project->title}}

Comment: Can you explain why you put this relationship? Will be great